# AngularJS curstom directive and ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to make an planification app with AngularJS. The main feature is to create a Task.
I want to put the source of the task in a directive :

```
<section id="runningTasks" ng-controller='RunningTaskCtrl as ctrl'>
    <task class="task" ng-repeat='task in ctrl.tasks'></task>
</section>
```

For each task, I add it in the div.
Here is my directive definition :

```
.directive('task', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace:'true',
        templateUrl: '/Planificator/directives/task/task.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            var date = $(element).find(".datepicker");
            date.datepicker();
            date.datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
        }
    };
})
```

And the content of task.html :

```
<div class="task" ng-click="task.editting = true" task>
    <h1>{{ task.title }}</h1>
    <p>
        {{ task.comment }}
    </p>
    <div class="edit-task" ng-show="task.editting">
        <form ng-submit="ctrl.propose(task)">
            ... form stuff ...
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is when I run my page, I get an error :

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$compile/multidir?p0=task&p1=task&p2=tem…3D%20true%22%20task%3D%22%22%20ng-repeat%3D%22task%20in%20ctrl.tasks%22%3E
    at Error (native)
```

(the clean link : [Angular error generator](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=task&p1=task&p2=template&p3=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22task%22%20ng-click%3D%22task.editting%20%3D%20true%22%20task%3D%22%22%20ng-repeat%3D%22task%20in%20ctrl.tasks%22%3E))

I already had this problem before and I just put the content of the template in the ngRepeat and doesn't think anymore, but this time I would like to be things in the good way.

Thank you for the answers !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
<div class="task" ng-click="task.editting = true" task>
```

Since this is part of the template created from the task directive you are trying to add the task directive over and over.

Change to:

```
<div class="task" ng-click="task.editting = true">
```